# Is there a symbolic formulation of modal realism?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, symbolic-logic, possible-worlds

Is there a symbolic formulation of modal realism, i.e. the doctrines of modal realism captured in some formal system?

Comment: Lewis came up with logics that *accomodate* modal realism, but it is impossible to formalize things like "possible worlds are as real as our world" or "possible worlds are causally isolated", those are metaphysical claims with all the vagueness of meaning that entails.

Comment: @Conifold can you post an answer with the best logic (according to Lewis)  accomodating modal realism?

Comment: Check out this paper for a short version http://www.ulrichmeyer.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Counterparts_Actuality.pdf it references Lewis's original works for a long one. I am not sure Lewis ever settled on the "best" version though, he first argued that the counterpart theory was better than QML because it was extensional, then changed his mind, etc.